# Running same DF template in parallel yields strange results

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I have a dataflow job that extracts data from Cloud SQL and loads it into Cloud Storage. We've configured the job to accept parameters so we can use the same code to extract multiple tables. The dataflow job is compiled as a template.

When we create/run instances of the template in serial we get the results we expect. However if we create/run instances in parallel only a few files turn up on Cloud Storage. In both cases we can see that the DF jobs are created and terminate sucessfully.

For example we have 11 instances which produce 11 output files. In serial we get all 11 files, in parallel we only get around 3 files. During the parallel run all 11 instances were running at the same time

Can anyone offer some advice as to why this is happening? I'm assuming that temporary files created by the DF template are somehow overwritten during the parallel run?

The main motivation of running in parallel is extracting the data more quickly.

**Edit**

The pipeline is pretty simple:

```
        PCollection<String> results =  p
            .apply("Read from Cloud SQL", JdbcIO.<String>read()
                .withDataSourceConfiguration(JdbcIO.DataSourceConfiguration
                        .create(dsDriver, dsConnection)
                        .withUsername(options.getCloudSqlUsername())
                        .withPassword(options.getCloudSqlPassword())
                )
                .withQuery(options.getCloudSqlExtractSql())
                .withRowMapper(new JdbcIO.RowMapper<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public String mapRow(ResultSet resultSet) throws Exception {
                        return mapRowToJson(resultSet);
                    }
                })
                .withCoder(StringUtf8Coder.of()));
```

When I compile the template I do

```
mvn compile exec:java \
 -Dexec.mainClass=com.xxxx.batch_ingestion.LoadCloudSql \
 -Dexec.args="--project=myproject \
    --region=europe-west1 \
    --stagingLocation=gs://bucket/dataflow/staging/ \
    --cloudStorageLocation=gs://bucket/data/ \
    --cloudSqlInstanceId=yyyy \
    --cloudSqlSchema=dev \
    --runner=DataflowRunner \
    --templateLocation=gs://bucket/dataflow/template/BatchIngestion"
```

When I invoke the template I also provide "tempLocation". I can see the dynamic temp locations are being used. Despite this I'm not seeing all the output files when running in parallel.

Thanks

Comment: Is there any chance that you could provide a bit some code, to show what you are executing? Is it possible to show at least the IO input source and sink steps of the pipeline. As well as the command line or create job UI screenshot, so we can see the parameters you are passing in. I suspect the issue may be that somehow the two pipelines are writing to the same GCS location, and possibly clear the GCS location over each other. I would also try making sure the two jobs use separate --tempLocation and --stagingLocation values, and see if that fixes the issue.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your suggestion, I've generated a dynamic tempLocation for each instance but still I'm seeing the issue - although perhaps not quite so bad. The target for all the jobs is the same CS location so I might try and generate a unique output location for each job and then move them back to a central location at the end....

Comment: Please try that as well and let me know if it helps. If you use the same GCS output location I believe they overwrite each other

Comment: Hi. I can confirm that adding a unique output location solved the issue. You can observe the behaviour in the logs - DF writes the temporary file to the output CS location first and then renames it. This would have caused files to have been overwritten

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution**

1. Add unique tempLocation
2. Add unique output path & filename
3. Move the output files to final destination on CS after DF completes its processing